# How to edit text drawn by Canvas.drawText()?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have made an Android app in which the user can write on a bitmap. There is an EditText in which the user types the text and a TextWatcher watches this text. The text is written on the bitmap using `Canvas.drawText()`. This works properly when text is typed in the EditText.

However, when I try to backspace some of the written text and write some other text, the text is not deleted on the bitmap. Instead, the new text is simply overwritten on the 'deleted' text.

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Can you get away with simply not drawing on the bitmap until the user is done editing?

Comment: @DeeV I can use that as a last resort, but I want to know if there is any other way. My idea is to provide a way to update the picture with the text as it is being typed.

Comment: Well, Canvas draws are like stamps.  It draws on the bitmap and it sticks there.  The only way overwrite a previous text is to redraw the entire box that the edittext is in.  If it's simple, you can get away with just calling `#invalidate(int, int, int, int);` where the parameters are the box.  If it's complex, like a photograph, you may have to redraw the entire bitmap which is why I suggested waiting.

Comment: @DeeV Yes, I think that's probably the best way forward. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

You can store the text displayed by Canvas.drawText and display that, and if you want to change that just use a setter to set the new text and then update the Canvas using the following methods:

Setting new text:

```
public void setText(String newText) {
    this.currentText = newText;
}
```

Updating Canvas:

```
public void update() {
    this.invalidate();
}
```

Just put both of the method into your view class.

Comment: What if more then one text is drawn on view by canvas ,Is all text is redraw?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can redraw your bitmap, and then your new text.

But a simpler way to do it (assuming you have a uniform background) is to first draw your current text in the same position using the background color (so erase everything), and then draw your new text.

Comment: Thanks, but my bitmaps are photographs, so there is no uniform background.

Comment: then you need to redraw your bitmap :(